# Medieval Music that sounds similar to opening of Stairway to Heaven by Led Zeppelin?

Tags: led-zeppelin

I'm looking for medieval music that sounds similar to opening of *Stairway to Heaven* by Led Zeppelin (the part without lyrics at the start): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oW_7XBrDBAA

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNtVN_B7U78

Harp, flute, medieval kind of feel, no lyrics, a somewhat nostalgic feel to it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please clarify you question, right now there's no actual question in there! :)

Comment: You would do better to look for music from the Renaissance style period rather than the Medieval period, if you want something with the musical texture you describe.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for "[Early Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_music)."  See if these meet your needs --these are all from YouTube searches for some combination of these terms: "flute", "harp", "lute", "early music", "renaissance."

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ov4XyUX6sQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0i3bklG1NU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fS25JiPa6fQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umAhE8xZaVE